# An Error occurs when cancel download from nest.js

Tags: express, download, nestjs

I tried to write some back-end APIs with nextjs.
And I encountered download problem.
I usually works well, but if I cancel downloading process, an error occurs in nestjs server.

Here is my code.

```
@Get(':encodedname')
public async downloadSingle(
  @Param('encodedname') encodedname: string,
  @Res({ passthrough: true }) res: Response,
): Promise<StreamableFile> {
  const { fileInfo } = await this.uploadsService.getFileInfo(encodedname);
  const file = createReadStream(
    join(process.cwd(), `./uploads/${fileInfo.filename}`),
  );
  res.set({
    'Content-Type': fileInfo.mimetype,
    'Content-Disposition': `${
      fileInfo.mimetype.indexOf('image') == 0 ||
      fileInfo.mimetype.indexOf('audio') == 0 ||
      fileInfo.mimetype.indexOf('video') == 0
        ? 'inline'
        : 'attachment'
    }; filename="${fileInfo.originalname}"`,
    'Content-Length': fileInfo.size,
  });
  return Promise.resolve(new StreamableFile(file));
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: share the error message with us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, I found that this error doesn't affect to the server.
So I skipped to handle this error.

There is another solution. Below code doesn't emit errors.

```js
try {
    res.pipe(file);
}
catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```